# Are filtered emails automatically forwarded in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

Let's say I have automatic forwarding enabled from my Gmail account (Account 1) to another Gmail account (Account 2), so all emails sent to Account 1 are automatically forwarded to Account 2.

If I create a filter in Account 1 which puts some incoming emails in the trash. Will these emails still be forwarded to Account 2? What if this filter is set to archive specific emails—would those be forwarded to Account 2?

Comment: content of the spam folder is not forwarded - for the rest it should work

Comment: I remember when I tested this long ago, emails deleted by filtering were not automatically forwarded. However, I don't want to create a delete filter—I'd rather archive or something similar. However, I'm not sure if it forwards it and unfortunately I am unable to check, so I was hoping someone would have some definite insight as to what prevents auto forwarding